# Spring framework boot does not exist?

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot

I am running the following application:

```
package com.h2o;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class H2oRestServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(H2oRestServiceApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

My pom.xml file can be found here: https://github.com/shilpakancharla/ReutersSearchEngine/blob/master/h2o/pom.xml

I am getting the following errors when trying to run javac

```
H2oRestServiceApplication.java from my terminal: 

H2oRestServiceApplication.java:3: error: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
                               ^
H2oRestServiceApplication.java:4: error: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
                                             ^
H2oRestServiceApplication.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
@SpringBootApplication
 ^
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
H2oRestServiceApplication.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        SpringApplication.run(H2oRestServiceApplication.class, args);
        ^
  symbol:   variable SpringApplication
  location: class H2oRestServiceApplication
4 errors
```

Could someone explain if there is something wrong with my pom.xml? I am not sure how to fix this or what dependencies I am missing.

Comment: You are running javac in the same folder where your application lays ?

Comment: Did you run a `build` so that the dependencies in your pom actually get downloaded? Running it from an IDE will be easier than using `javac` in terminal.

Comment: Yes, I am in the same folder that I'm running it in.

Comment: @Kartik I don not think I have done that. How do I do that?

Comment: please follow [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#use-maven) and [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/) guide

Comment: @user10335564 can you please right click on project select maven click update project configuration tick force updAte of snapshots/releases and then click ok.

Comment: Why are you running `javac` yourself? You should use maven to run that, so you can build a proper class path.

Answer (score 2):

I have done the below steps and your application is up and running -- I was able to view the swagger UI as well.

1) Cloned your repository

```
git clone https://github.com/shilpakancharla/ReutersSearchEngine.git
```

2) Switched to your project directory

```
cd ReutersSearchEngine/h2o
```

3) Did a Maven Clean Package (as your's is a maven based spring boot project)

```
mvn clean package
```

Waited for maven to download dependencies, compile sources and build an executable jar.

It created a jar with name `h2o-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` inside `target` directory.

4) Simply launched the jar file using the below command.

```
java -jar target/h2o-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The application started fine with these logs at the end.

```
2018-11-19 16:56:01.928  INFO 7288 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 80 (http) with context path ''
2018-11-19 16:56:01.932  INFO 7288 --- [           main] com.h2o.H2oRestServiceApplication        : Started H2oRestServiceApplication in 8.595 seconds (JVM running for 9.116)
```

5) As the application started on port `80`, I visited the below address on my browser.

```
http://localhost/swagger-ui.html
```

And your swagger-ui showed up as below.

[image]

Hope this helps!

If you still face issues, please post it here.